# how to send a link when user asks for alexa skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there any method to send a link to a user when they ask through an Alexa skill? I found Send to Phone Intent but I didn't understand how to implement it. Has anyone had to use this intent? The scenery would be as an example: Alexa, open the amazon website and it would send a push notification to the cell phone and when the customer clicked on the notification it would open the amazon website.

Answer (score 0):

The Send to Phone feature should do exactly what you're describing, but it's in developer preview right now, so [you need to apply here](https://build.amazonalexadev.com/2021_Alexa_Apps_Send_Interest.html) to gain access.

In the meantime, here are the [tech docs](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-for-apps/about-alexa-for-apps.html), [design guidelines](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-haus/send-to-phone), and a [code sample](https://github.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-alexa-for-apps).